# Creating a color theme using adobe kular

Tags: color, color-theory, adobe-kuler

I am trying to create a color theme to my website using adobe kuler. I am really new to that app and confusing how to create a theme there.

This is my main color - #53001e

Can any body tell me what are the other colors that might be match to this main color?

Thank You.

Comment: Hi there! This has been asked an answered quite a few times, take a look at the linked question. It's good to start with some color theory instead of asking for a specific color that is unlikely to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Kuler helps you to determine specific analogous, complimentary, etc colors. But it will not create the color harmony for you. Any harmony need to be created manually. As for your case, I have done one that can be a good starting point.

[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer. can I use these colors in my website? are these colors match with my main color?

Comment: Yes, all provided colors based on color theory and can be used in different ways. For sure, don't forget about the white color.

Comment: How about this color #d62107? is not match with my main color?

Comment: It is analogous color, but due high brightness is not fits exactly. But this is not means that you can't use it. It can works very well for CTAs and other purposes for attracting high attention.

Comment: Vnovak, What is analogous color? and what are the others?

Comment: @ugnuku, you can check some information about it here: http://www.tigercolor.com/color-lab/color-theory/color-harmonies.htm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14962/discussion-between-ugnuku-and-vnovak).

Answer (score 0):

Despite what the user before said these specific colors such as complementary and analogous are COLOR HARMONIES.

Basically you just choose one color and choose the color rule you want and it creates a color harmony for you.

Comment: Harmony=Math? Not sure..

Comment: http://www.tigercolor.com/color-lab/color-theory/color-harmonies.htm pretty much good summary of color harmonies. If you want to dig deeper I suggest to watch this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qj1FK8n7WgY